# Why two stitched shapes create this strange lines when subdivision modifier is applied?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I've created an arm and a hand separatedly, then I joined them, after that, I took the vertices and connected them together to create new faces. Everything looks fine with the basic shape

[image: normal mesh]

But once I apply some subdivision as a modifier then some really easy to spot lines appear :( basically on those two areas that I've merged together, what can I do to fix this? thanks!

[image: issue]

Comment: I've run into this several times - it's always a relief to remember those sneaky internal edges/faces!

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, two edges were automatically generated within that shape that was causing this problem :)! edges disolved, the issue disappeared. thanks anyway!

[image: solved]